# Getting timeout error when testing ajax behavior within ember component with sinon and mocha

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to test an ember component with mocha and sinon. I wanted to test one of the actions of the component which makes an ajax call by using sinon's  "useFakeXMLHttpRequest". But this test is causing time-out error. I am using mocha test adapter for ember taken from https://github.com/teddyzeenny/ember-mocha-adapter, I couldn't find the js file in cloud so I have pasted in whole code - so it might look bit messy in the jsbin.

Here is a jsbin link to the issue : http://jsbin.com/usajOhE/1/

The code for the component is :

```
        AS.QuestionViewComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
            templateName: "components/question-view",
            actions: {
                makeAjaxCall: function() {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/todo/items",
                        success: function(data) {

                            //callback(null, data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
```

The handle bar associated with the component is :

```
<a {{action "makeAjaxCall"}} class="test-link">Make ajax call</a>
```

And my test script is:

```
        describe("Testing", function() {


            var xhr, requests;
            before(function() {

                xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
                requests = [];
                xhr.onCreate = function(req) {
                    requests.push(req);
                };

            });

            after(function() {
                xhr.restore();
            });

            beforeEach(function() {
                AS.reset();
                visit("/");
            });

            it("shoud make ajax call", function() {
                //TIMESOUT HERE                   
                click($("a.test-link:first")).then(function() {
                    console.log(requests);
                    expect(requests.length).to.be(1);
                });
            });
        });
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it is because you have not responded to the fake ajax request. The `ember-testing` package counts the pending ajax requests made by jQuery ([see pendingAjaxRequests here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers.js#L14)). If this stays at 1, the ember-testing `wait()` helper never resolves.

The `ember-testing` package increments this counter via [ajaxStart and ajaxStop filters](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers.js#L17).

To clarify what's happening here: When you use the `click()` helper, this sends a click message to the element, and then **defers to the `wait()` helper** (a promise). The same applies for other helpers such as `fillIn()`, `keyEvent()` etc. You can see from the comments in the source for `wait()` that it will not progress on with the rest of your specs:

```
// 1. If the router is loading
// 2. *If there are pending Ajax requests
// 3. If there are scheduled timers or we are inside of a run loop
```

The fix:

Unfortunately, if you never make it to the `then` block of your test, you cannot fake a response via `requests[0].respond(...)`.

Instead, I've solved this by using sinon's fake server:

```
var server;

beforeEach(function () {
  server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  server.autoRespond = true;
  server.autoRespondAfter = 1; // ms
  App.reset();
});

afterEach(function () {
  server.restore();
});

it("should make ajax call", function() {
  // set up the fake response
  server.responses[0].response = [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, '{ "todos": [] }'];

  visit('/')
  .click($("a.test-link:first"))
  .then(function() {
    // should make it to here now
  });
});
```

This pattern works fine when you are expecting a single, or a deterministic order of ajax requests going into your fake server. If you expect lots of requests (with different paths), you can use `server.respondWith([regex], ...)` to match certain urls to specific responses.

Another thing to note is that it's generally good practice to put the success part of your ajax call into an Ember.run:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/todo/items",
  success: function(data) {
    Ember.run(function () {
      //callback(null, data);
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the detailed response. I will try your fix and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry it took me quite a while to get back to this, but thanks a lot.

Comment: In ie8 somehow we were still getting these random timeout errors, but after setting this.timeout(TIME IN SECONDS) to some larger value, it solved the issue.